# IntelliJ unable to detect code coverage - reports 0% coverage

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, testng, code-coverage

I'm currently working on a project with about 48% test coverage. TeamCity, which is set to use IntelliJ code coverage, is able to report on it but the IDE itself seems to think I have 0% coverage.

[image]

It's a maven project and I'm using IntelliJ 14.0.3 Ultimate. TestNG 6.8.21 is being used as the testing framework.

Comment: How do you execute your application for coverage report? Maybe you use just subset of your tests so these classes are really not executed.

Comment: I right-click on the entire test package and select run with coverage so the whole lot should be in the report.

Comment: I have the same issue. The tests run OK , but no covrage.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the test class have the same pacakge/directory path as the class you want to test. For example test for `com.google.service.UserService` has `package com.google.service` in the test directory. I guess that how IDEA infer test classes' paths.

It works for me.